# How to set the "viewfields" property to true in C#

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to set the viewfields property = true in C# inorder to get at some values I need in the "ows_MetaInfo" attribute returned from a "Getlistitems" SOAP call. How do I go about doing this if I am creating my XML with code?

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
            System.Xml.XmlElement query = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query");
            System.Xml.XmlElement viewFields = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields");
            System.Xml.XmlElement rowLimit = xmlDoc.CreateElement("RowLimit");
            System.Xml.XmlElement queryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions");
            System.Xml.XmlElement webID = xmlDoc.CreateElement("WebID");
```

after first looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc264031.aspx i tried setting the viewFields property with no luck:

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
            System.Xml.XmlElement query = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query");
            System.Xml.XmlElement viewFields = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields");
            viewFields.SetAttribute("Properties", "True");
            System.Xml.XmlElement rowLimit = xmlDoc.CreateElement("RowLimit");
            System.Xml.XmlElement queryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions");
            System.Xml.XmlElement webID = xmlDoc.CreateElement("WebID");
```

Answer (score 3):

The [[MS-LISTSWS]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313068%28v=office.12%29.aspx) specification says:

> ViewFields.Properties: If True and the MetaInfo field is referenced in a FieldRef element, then properties related to the list item will be returned in the protocol server response with the prefix "ows_MetaInfo_".

So you should include a `<FieldRef Name="MetaInfo" />` within the `<ViewFields>` element.